# Can I change the firefox master password request dialog

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm implementing a new firefox master password type (with addon-sdk). Therefor I need to modify the master password request dialog. I researched that it is from "nsIPrompt", but can I change it somehow for my addon? I don't want to override the "commonDialog.xul", because I'm using the addon-sdk.

Background to this question:
I'm implementing a dynamic master password, in which you can choose between different password types (e.g. text-based or graphical passwords). So, depending on what type you have chossen, the master password request dialog needs to be modified.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Please clarify your question, and what you actually what to know. As written, the answer to your stated question is: "Yes." Please see: [ask], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes you can change it, this addon here does this - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/master-password/?src=search